# Is Depth-First Search a complete strategy?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Im doing a few past exam papers in prep for my examination. One of the questions is
 "Comment on each, is this strategy a complete strategy?

i: depth first search

ii: iterative deepening search

iii: breath first search

Now my answer is that no depth first is not because it searches the most recently generated node. As for iterative deepening id say yes because it has a maximum depth that is increased through repetition. Finally im completely sure breath first is a complete method.

If anyone could verify my answers or explain to me where i have gone wrong that would be great. Also by complete i mean that it is certain to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

Depth first search is not complete. If the tree depth is infinite, it may never actually find a solution.

Iterative Deepening search is complete. It searches complete tree within a given depth and doubles the depth every iteration (although this strategy may vary).

Breath first search is complete as it searches level wise.